# why i get NullPointerException when i try to visit member variables after force type convert?

Tags: java, stack, type-conversion

I create a class `Node` which contains an int variable `val`
When I try to get the `val` after I pop it from stack, the compiler throw a `NullPointerException`. 
Does anyone knows how to fix this?

```
public class Node{
  int val;
  Node left;
  Node right;
  Node(int x) {val = x;}
}


Node root = new Node(6);
Stack s = new Stack();
s.push(root);
Node node = (Node)s.pop();
System.out.println(node.val);
```

Comment: + your code works for me. How are you running the code ?

Comment: Me too.  Try fully qualifying `Stack` (i.e.  replace `Stack` with `java.util.Stack`)

Comment: You should also not need to do the classcast, you can use generics (`Stack<Node> s = new Stack<>()`)